# Visual studio .SLN executing Exe file / .VBS script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

How to launch .Exe file or .VBS script when visual studio solution(.sln) is opened ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: And what do you mean by "opened"? Double-Clicking in Explorer, opening from Visual Studio, ...?

Comment: I want to delete some files, when programmer clicks on the solution

Comment: "opened" :-> double click on "windows explorer" / open it through visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

Associate a .SLN file with your own executable instead of `devenv`.  In your executable, if the solution being opened matches then delete the necessary files. Then execute the `devenv` and pass the solution full path and name as a parameter.

Comment: But i want to do it the other way.

Comment: I appreciate the solution, for me rest of the .sln files which i have in my machine  should work normally, only this particular .sln (test.sln) should work differently... That is the reason i want to execute the exe from .sln.

Comment: I doubt whether a solution is there for my problem :-)

Comment: I don't see why this solution would not work - in case of all other .sln files, the exe would basically be a pass-through.